# Integral representation of Hermite polynomials

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, special-functions

I would like to go from the generating function, $g(x,t)$ of the Hermite polynomials $H_n(x)$,

$$ g(x,t) = e^{-t^2 + 2tx} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}$$

to the following representation,

$$H_n(x) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} e^{x^2} \oint  \frac{e^{-z^2}}{(z+x)^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}z $$

where the contour encloses the point $z=-x$.

I know that I am supposed to use the Cauchy integral formula, but I am having troubles. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $g(x,t)$ not  having any finite poles (entire in  $t$) the Cauchy
Coefficient Formula certainly applies. We get

$$H_n(x) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|t|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{t^{n+1}} \exp(-t^2+2tx) \; dt.$$

This is

$$ \frac{n!\times \exp(x^2)}{2\pi i}
\int_{|t|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{t^{n+1}} \exp(-t^2+2tx-x^2) \; dt
\\ = \frac{n!\times \exp(x^2)}{2\pi i}
\int_{|t|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{t^{n+1}} \exp(-(t-x)^2) \; dt.$$

With the substitution $z=t-x$ we have $dz  = dt$ and the radius of the
small circle is preserved, and we make one turn. We find

$$\frac{n!\times \exp(x^2)}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z+x|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{(z+x)^{n+1}} \exp(-z^2) \; dz$$

as claimed. The references for the CCF are *Analytic Combinatorics* by
Flajolet and Sedgewick, e.g. pages 246 and 732.